# Hiding extension methods for certain generic types in IntelliSense

Tags: c#, extension-methods, intellisense

I have an extension method:

```
public static void Foo<T>(this MyClass<T> target)
    where T : IEnumerable
{
    // Code goes here
}
```

I want to hide this extension method from InteliSense if T is a string but not for other types in the same way that the Extension methods for IEnumerable in Linq is hidden when you are working with a string.
I have looked at the `EditorBrowsableAttribute` but it does not seem to allow hiding a method based on the generic type.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the `EditorBrowsableAttribute` to this method (and maybe to the class that containts this method, too) and relocate the method to another assembly (another project). After that, compile the assembly and unload the project, so you would have only the DLL reference. This is the only way to use the power of `EditorBrowsableAttribute`.

Comment: I want the method visible in IntelliSense, I just want it not visible when `T` is `string`
`EditorBrowsableAttribute` hides it for all methods.

Comment: @Cornelius this is not possible semantically since `string` clearly and explicitly implements both `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<char>`. You just can't do anything about this.

Comment: @Cornelius the only thing you could try is to create overloads that will accept all your types you need except for `char` as the `T` for `IEnumerable`.